# Difference between F11 and Ctrl + F11 in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, debugging, shortcut

Am able to run my java file using both the shortcuts, what is the difference? which one has to be preferred among? Further does it give us any problems choosing wrong option ?

Comment: Based on [this](https://shortcutworld.com/en/Eclipse/win/all), it's the difference between running the code with or without the debugger attached.  No, there's nothing wrong with using either, but if you want to add breakpoints and debug the code, you should be [ctrl]+[F11]

Comment: you can change your shortcut actions:

Go to Window>Preferences>General>Keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of F11 key you can run your application normally, But if you have any breakpoints in your application, eclipse will launch your application in debug perspective.Well if you want to skip debug perspective, than you can use ctrl + F11 to run your application normally.